How do I replicate the Split View Mode and Compare buttons from BIM360 in APS Viewer?
I have a next.js app incorporating Autodesk Platform Services viewer to display Revit models. A request has come in to replicate Split View Mode and Compare buttons on the toolbar, which are on by default in BIM360. These look like they should be extensions, but I can't find them. Do they exist? And if they don't, how can I replicate the functionality?
// handle the split screen button
      let splitScreenButton = new Autodesk.Viewing.UI.Button(
        "splitScreenButton"
      );

      let isSplitScreenLoaded = false;

      splitScreenButton.onClick = function () {
        if (isSplitScreenLoaded) {
          newViewer.unloadExtension("Autodesk.SplitScreen");
          isSplitScreenLoaded = false;
        } else {
          newViewer.loadExtension("Autodesk.SplitScreen");
          isSplitScreenLoaded = true;
        }
      };
      splitScreenButton.setToolTip("Split Screen");
      splitScreenButton.setIcon("adsk-icon-second");

      compareTools.addControl(splitScreenButton);

      // coppied straight from the docs, and typically, dosent work
      let compareButton = new Autodesk.Viewing.UI.Button("compareButton");
      let isCompareLoaded = false;
      var config = {
        availableDiffModes: ["overlay", "sidebyside"],
        // diffModels: A,
        // primaryModels: B,
        mimeType: "application/vnd.autodesk.revit",
        diffadp: false,
        diffMode: "overlay",
        // versionA: "A",
        // versionB: "B",
        propertyFilter: { Category1: ["Property1", "Property2"] },
      };
      compareButton.onClick = function () {
        if (isCompareLoaded) {
          newViewer.unloadExtension("Autodesk.DiffTool", config);
          isCompareLoaded = false;
        } else {
          newViewer.loadExtension("Autodesk.DiffTool", config);
          isCompareLoaded = true;
        }
      };
      compareButton.setToolTip("Compare");
      compareButton.setIcon("adsk-icon-live-review");

      compareTools.addControl(compareButton);

split screen mode only displays the model twice, not super useful. The same can be said for the docs. Idealy i can replace what i have with
newViewer.loadExtension("Autodesk.SplitViewMode")
or something similar, but im having no luck finding it.
Same question for the compare function.
Thanks in advance.

Here's a blog article that describes what you want to achieve: Difference 3D models Autodesk DiffTool Extension

As @AlexAR mentioned already in his comment, there's a viewer extension you can use to compare two versions of a design side-by-side: https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/difference-3d-models-autodeskdifftool-extension.
